# Analyze the log categorize and store it in Elasticsearch Index

Tags: java, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, bigdata

I am having multiple log files from different components say `A`, `B` and `C`.
Each components has different log format. How can I analyze the log in each of the components and store the extracted data in Elasticsearch Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Logstash application. Logstash parses your log files -> outputs into an elastic search index. Look here: [Elastic Search: LogStash Product](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)